# Referenceproblem using SmartThreadPool in Mono for Android

Tags: reference, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop, threadpool

I want to use [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool) in a Mono for Android Application. Unfortunatley I am getting an error, when I reference the SmartThreadPool.dll from the project:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets(2,2): 
Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for 
Android profile?
File name: 'System.Web.dll'
at Monodroid.Tuner.MonoDroidResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, 
ReaderParameters parameters)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 
assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()
```

I already tried to put the library under the Assets folder and set its BuildAction to AndroidAssets as read in http://adnankhan12.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/android-mono-error-using-other-dlls-novell-monodroid-common-targets. But still it does not work.

At the moment, I am not able to use SmartThreadPool, but on the webpage of the project mono support is stated explicitly. So what am I missing or doing wrong?

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API Reference documentation](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/) the only class accessible from the namespace `System.Web` is `HttpUtility` class.

You might be right that Mono does have `SmartThreadPool`, however it is not included in Mono for Android and MonoTouch.

You can see which assemblies ship with [Mono for Android here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/guides/advanced_topics/assemblies), and for [MonoTouch here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/guides/advanced_topics/Assemblies).

**EDIT:**
Also the DLL you are referencing is not built with either the Mono for Android or Monotouch compile and hence you will have troubles referencing it in your project. You also need to be aware of dependencies it might have.